# Migrated database in rails but no tables found?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to migrate my database in rails but no tables are found. Using development environment only and steps I'm taking are through Lynda rails 2010 tutorials. Any help would be much appreciated. Info below

```
NOC-4:app noc$ rake db:migrate
(in /Users/noc/rails_projects/app)
==  CreateUsers: migrating ====================================================
-- create_table(:users)
   -> 0.0566s
==  CreateUsers: migrated (0.0567s) ===========================================

NOC-4:app noc$ mysql -u simple_cms -p simple_cms_development
Enter password: 
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 15
Server version: 5.5.20 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SHOW TABLES
    ->
```

Below is my database.yml

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: simple_cms_development
  username: simple_cms
  password: secretpassword
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be eased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake". 
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql
  database: simple_cms_test
  username: simple_cms
  password: 
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: simple_cms_development
  username: simple_cms
  password: 
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

also is my needed info from my Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'ruby-mysql'
gem 'activerecord'
gem 'mysql'
gem 'rake', '~> 0.8.7'

gem 'therubyracer', :require => 'v8'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where's your semicolon, dude?

```
mysql> show tables;
```

Comment: wow....Thx jibiel....I'm a cisco and juniper guy getting into dev specifically rails. Thx mate ;)

Comment: @beach180 Boy, this is hilarious. Btw don't you mind to accept my superanswer?

Comment: umm...new to stackoverflow....how do I accept a superanswer? Checking up require me to have 15 reputation ;(

Comment: There's huge checkbox on the left side of the answer under that zero. Guess you can hit it. Welcome and feel free to RTFM before hitting stackoverflow :)